# Can someone explain ordering relations?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I have been reading axiomatic set theory by Patrick Suppes and have been having a hard time with the different types of ordering relations. The relations are quasi-ordering, partial orderings, simple orderings, strict partial orderings, and strict simple orderings. The book defines them in terms of reflexivity, transitivity, asymmetry, and antisymmetry, but I have been gotten them mixed up more times than I can count. If someone could provide examples to help me solidify these ideas, the help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As you said, the difference is due to the different properties that hold in the various cases. E.g. $=$ is reflexive while $<$ is not.

Comment: Is there possibly an easier way to remember which one is which? My main problem is remembering which ones are reflexive, transitive, etc. and which ones are not. Or will I simply have to memorize them as is? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try to memorize partial vs simple first (for simple, for every two different elements, one must be bigger and the other smaller). Memorize strict, that is $<$ vs non-strict $\le$, that is equal elements are related when the order is non-strict (partial or simple), but they cannot be related when the order is strict. That takes care of four of the cases you list, so when you are comfortable with them there will be only one more, quasi-ordering, that you need to memorize. That is when you could have $x\le y$ and $y\le x$, yet not necessarily $y=x$. Sleep it over.